# Utilizar QTableView con un modelo de datos haciendo la lectura con el módulo pymysql

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

Estoy tratando de utilizar **QTableView** con un modelo de datos haciendo la lectura de una base de datos MySql con el módulo **pymysql**.

Se visualiza la tabla y la cabecera, pero en el método *data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole)* el parámetro **index** no contiene un valor correcto para el número de filas, *index.row()* da un valor inferior al resultante de la consulta. En todos los demás métodos los valores que llegan son los esperados.

¿Alguna idea?

En el código basta con poner una base datos MySql y adaptar el SELECT.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QTableView,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget
    )

import pymysql


class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, header_data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = data
        self._header_data = header_data

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if self.rowCount() > 0:
            return len(self._data[0])
        return 0

    # todo bien hasta que el proceso llega aquí
    # y me encuentro que el parámetro index 
    # tiene mal el número de filas 
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data[index.row()][index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._header_data[section])
        return None


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PySide6 MySQL Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        self.table_view = QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.table_view)

        # Connect to MySQL database
        connection = pymysql.connect(host=DB_HOST,
                                     user=DB_USER,
                                     password=DB_PASS,
                                     database=DB_NAME,
                                     charset='utf8mb4',
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                # Read data from MySQL
                cursor.execute("SELECT cmapo01, campo02, campo03 FROM tabla")
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                # Get column names
                header_data = [field[0] for field in cursor.description]
                # Create model and set to table view
                self.model = MyTableModel(data, header_data)
                self.table_view.setModel(self.model)
        finally:
            connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: No conozco del todo el escenario, pero no sería más conveniente crear un [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html) y meter todos los datos allí usando el modelo default?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Para quien pueda interesar.

Al hacer uso de una consulta vía **pymysql** el resultado no es una lista, sino un **diccionario**, por lo que la función que toma los datos debe quedar:

```
def data(self, index, role): #Qt.DisplayRole
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        column_key = self._header_data[index.column()]
        return str(self._data[index.row()][column_key])
    return None
```